# WordPress: Function Declaration WC_Gateway_PayPal_Pro_PayFlow::get_post_data($order) should be compatible with WC_Settings_API::get_post_data()

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, paypal, woocommerce

I am running WooCommerce (v3.3.5) within WordPress (v4.9.5).

I am using PayPal Pro gateway (v4.3.3) to process credit card transactions.

PayPal Pro gateway function declaration is not correct and now getting the following warning thousands of times daily in the error logs.

`[Thu Apr 26 09:47:52.536393 2018] [:error] [pid 641] [client 54.255.254.245:57848] PHP Warning:  Declaration of WC_Gateway_PayPal_Pro_PayFlow::get_post_data($order) should be compatible with WC_Settings_API::get_post_data() in /html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-pro/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-pro-payflow.php on line 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot update to the latest version of PayPal Pro plug-in available, you can rename the function in `wp-plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-pro/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-pro-payflow.php` file:

```
ln 433    public function get_post_data( $order ) {
```

Becomes:

```
ln 433    public function _get_post_data( $order ) {
```

Then update where it's called:

```
ln 235    $post_data = $this->_get_post_data( $order );
ln 546    $post_data            = $this->_get_post_data( $order );
```